# Access a variable outside of a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to access a variable outside of the following while loop:

```
  $resources = "select * from resources where stage LIKE '%".$stage."%'";

        $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $resources);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {

        $format = $row['format'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $costs = $row['cost'];
         $stage = $row['stage'];
         $topic = $row['topic'];
         $link = $row['link'];
       }




// Email subject
  $subject = "subject!";
  $subject_us = "New custom resource delivered to: $clean_email";

  $message = '<html><body>';
  $message .= "<p>";
  $message .= "Hi $clean_fullName, <br><br>";
  $message .= " Based on your responses, we have created a custom resource pack tailored to your needs.  <br><br>";
  $message .= "<b>$title</b><br>";
  $message .= "$format <br>";
  $message .= "$costs <br>";
  $message .= "$link <br><br>";
```

[...]
The reason why I do not want to include the mail items in the while loop its because it will send out 10 emails for example for each title, rather than one email with all title, which is why i do not want to include inside the while loop.

Problem is that I cannot access the items inside the while loop and include it below.

Comment: Use arrays for each column in the loop, then iterate through your arrays in the email.

Comment: You can save the variables into an array

Comment: which is a better approach?

Comment: Why access them outside the loop? The `@message =` could be before the loop, and all the `message .=` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, an array would be your best option.

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
    // add to data
    $data[] = array(
        'format' => $row['format'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'costs' => $row['cost'],
        'stage' => $row['stage'],
        'topic' => $row['topic'],
        'link' => $row['link']
    );
}
```

Simple enough right? Now comes the logical part. All you have to do here is loop through your above `$data` array to send each email off.

```
foreach($data as $item) {
    // Email subject
    $subject = "subject!";
    $subject_us = "New custom resource delivered to: $clean_email";

    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= "<p>";
    $message .= "Hi $clean_fullName, <br><br>";
    $message .= " Based on your responses, we have created a custom resource pack tailored to your needs.  <br><br>";
    $message .= "<b>{$item['title]}</b><br>";
    $message .= "{$item['format']} <br>";
    $message .= "{$item['costs']} <br>";
    $message .= "{$item['link']} <br><br>";
}
```

I assume you're sending it to the clients right? Cause I don't see where you set `$clean_email` or `$clean_fullName` anywhere.

Comment: Yeah I have defined clean_email and clean_fullname above. SHould they included within the foreach as well as the mail       mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @kitttkittybangbang and @Maverick.

If you want to access your variables use `foreach` loop and at the same time stored that in array variable.

For example:

Declare at the top of `while` loop

```
  $arrVar = []; // empty array variable
```

Inside `while` loop create an array variable.

```
   $arrVar[] = ['format' => $format, 'title' => $title, 'costs' => $costs, 'stage' => $stage, 'topic' => $topic, 'link' => $link];
    print_r($arrVar);  //prints result
```

Then outside your `while` loop use.

```
       foreach($arrVar as $key => $val) {
        //do what you want here
     }
```

Hope this helps.